# reading current state of thread without using global variable

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor and it manages 2 Worker threads (Callables). My  Worker thread job is to listen to MQ and write content to a file and update count. My requirement is when total messages read by all threads equal to total messages submitted, I need to stop my worker threads by passing STOP message. How do I get the count from my worker thread in my parent thread while its still running.

I checked API for ThreadPoolExecutor, It only has beforeExecute and afterExecute. afterExecute will not work for me because my thread should be stopped first before getting to afterExecute.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just set a flag on the queue when it's no longer required and let the worker thread die when they see that flag?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are going the wrong way, if your worker threads are actively polling for new messages or are running for more than one request.

The idea of `Threadpoolexecutor` is, that a `Callable` represents one task (which is, in your example: processing one message). If you do that, you can employ `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()` to close your workerthreads. If you do so, you only have to have one central instance, which keeps track of the amount of messages to be expected and messages processed and executes the shutdown method after `processed == expected`

Edit: You don't have to monitor the Thread-states if you follow that pattern, because `TPE.shutdown()` will not prevent the execution of already submitted tasks but will only disallow further submissions.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for reply. My requirement is to have 5 listener threads listening to MQ and each thread will write the message from Queue to an output file. Finally the parent thread will merge all these 5 output files and emails it. I understand Callable should represent one task but if there are 5000 messages on my queue, there will be 5000 output files which I should merge later. Do you think if there is another way of achieving this with ThreadPoolExecutor? Thanks Again.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether Threadpool is the correct concept for your problem. Why do you hope to speed up your application by using 5 threads? Without knowing your setup its hard to suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Have the parent thread instantiate an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and pass it to the workers. They can invoke `incrementAndGet()` on it, and the parent thread can then read this when it's running. You could even have the worker threads check that the result after the `incrementAndGet()` is less than the threshold, and if it's over, the worker can stop itself and/or issue the stop command to the other workers; that way, you don't even need the parent thread's involvement, the workers will just shut themselves down when they've hit the threshold.

If you want the parent thread to block until they're all done, you could also create a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) initialized with the threshold, and then just have each worker call `countDown()` while the parent thread calls `await()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable and have a synchronized access to this static variable from your parent and worker thread.

Lets us say, you have a global static variable **count**

Now,

```
private static int count;

public static synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
}

public static synchronized void decrement() {
    count--;
}
```

Now in you're worker therad, whenever you take an item from MQ and process it in you're worker thread increment this by calling the snynchronized increment method.

In you're parent thread when the count is equal to total no. of items submitted, do ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()